# Test on Android Native App (calculator) with Protractor throwing error

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, protractor, appium

I wanted to automate a native app (calculator app) on Android using protractor. When I tried with the following configuration, I'm getting this error after app got launched and closed:

> WebDriverError: Method has not yet been implemented

Is there solution for this? Here is my code:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

specs: ['spec.js'],
capabilities:{
    'appium-version': '1.5.3',
     platformName: 'Android',
     platformVersion: '5.1.1',
     deviceName: 'Nexus 5',
     browserName: "android",         
     appPackage: 'com.android.calculator2',
     appActivity: '.Calculator',
     newCommandTimeout: 6000,        
     fulReset: true
}
onPrepare: function () {
    var wd = require('wd'),
        protractor = require('protractor'),
        wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
}
};

it("",function(){
   element(by.id('com.android.calculator2:id/digit_7')).click();
    element(by.name('minus')).click();
    element(by.id('com.android.calculator2:id/digit_3')).click();
    element(by.name('equals')).click();
});
```

Comment: Does the error report the line number of the failing code?  Also, not sure if this is your problem, but I believe you have a typo in your config.  `fulReset: true` should be `fullReset: true`

Comment: I don't think this is yet supported, see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1940